# Select rows in a many-to-many that exactly match inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server

With 3 tables (Thread, Tag, ThreadTag), I'm trying to select threads that have all of the tags provided in the query. In this example, I need the thread(s) that have tags of 'fedex' and 'shipping', so the expected result is 2 rows: ThreadIDs 1 and 4.

Thread Table

```
+----------+----------------------------------+
| ThreadID |           ThreadTitle            |
+----------+----------------------------------+
|        1 | Can I choose Fedex for shipping? |
|        2 | Is Shipping Free                 |
|        3 | Can I use a credit card?         |
|        4 | Does Fedex ship next day?        |
|        5 | Is Fedex reliable?               |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Tag Table

```
+-------+-------------+
| TagID |   TagName   |
+-------+-------------+
|     1 | shipping    |
|     2 | fedex       |
|     3 | ups         |
|     4 | price       |
|     5 | free        |
|     6 | credit card |
+-------+-------------+
```

ThreadTag Table

```
+----------+-------+
| ThreadID | TagID |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |     1 |
|        1 |     2 |
|        1 |     3 |
|        2 |     1 |
|        2 |     5 |
|        3 |     6 |
|        4 |     1 |
|        4 |     2 |
|        5 |     2 |
+----------+-------+
```

Here is the code that I came up with:

```
WITH ThreadsWithMatchingTags AS (
  SELECT ThreadID
  FROM ThreadTag tt
  INNER JOIN Tag t on tt.TagID = t.TagID
  WHERE TagName IN ('shipping', 'fedex')
  GROUP BY ThreadID
  HAVING COUNT(ThreadID) = 2
) 
SELECT *
FROM Thread
WHERE ThreadID IN (SELECT ThreadID FROM ThreadsWithMatchingTags)
```

OUTPUT:

```
+----------+----------------------------------+
| ThreadID |           ThreadTitle            |
+----------+----------------------------------+
|        1 | Can I choose Fedex for shipping? |
|        4 | Does Fedex ship next day?        |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```

which works, but there's gotta be a better way.

Comment: Why?  Your method is fine.

Comment: You could use an inner join instead of IN() and a subquery instead of CTE but the execution plans are probably very similar

Comment: Do you need   `GROUP BY ThreadID
  HAVING COUNT(ThreadID) = 2 `  in your query?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the other way of writing your query.

```
SELECT * from Thread th
WHERE(SELECT COUNT(*) from Tag ta, ThreadTag tt
WHERE ta.TagID = tt.TagID 
AND tt.ThreadID = th.ThreadID
AND ta.TagName in ('fedex', 'shipping')) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

"Better" is subjective and I always compare the optimizer output as there's nothing wrong with your solution.

Having said that, I'd do something like this: -

```
select
    a.*
from
    Thread a
where 
    (
    select
        count(*)
    from
        Tag       b,
        ThreadTag c
    where
        c.ThreadID = a.ThreadID and
        b.TagID    = c.TagID    and
        b.TagName in ('shipping', 'fedex')
    ) = 2;
```